# Tortoise SVN - export target-specific files

Tags: svn, export, tortoisesvn, tagging

I'm running Tortoise-SVN 1.9.1 on a local WAMP-maschine with tag-branch-trunk-structure. I am publishing html&php-code to several servers
that each has a few files that are specific for that server (holding username/password-entries or the local path setup).

Before starting to use svn, there were file-versions of those (credentials-)files for every server and when publishing to a certain server, the correct set of server-specific files had to be choosen. 
Now, with svn, I make a branch for the new version and tag server-specific packages, still choosing the correct specific files manually together.
I had hoped that with svn this could be automated in any way to get rid of errors.

Can somebody please give me a hint, what would be the best practice to tag all but a few plus 3 certain files to tag "server_A" and
all but a few plus 3 different files to tag "server_B".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion is based on using svn but is not the best way to do it. The best answer for your requirement would be to create a build script to create a zip file for each server by lifting files from the trunk and server specific folders (also in trunk) and packaging them together. Look at ant for a simple build system. You then just need to tag your trunk folder and you are done.

However if you prefer to do it in svn as per your question, this is how to do it.

- Files in trunk are the files for your main development
- Create a branch for each server specific distribution
- In each of these branches put your server specific changes with the passwords and commit.
- Whenever you make changes to trunk that need to make it to all servers you have to merge trunk to each branch (I would do this with a small batch file at the command line). Commit each branch
- At this point each branch will have a correct version of the code for each server.
- You can then tag the whole of the branches folder or even the whole repo as the release number.